# Locating Bot Username on Slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slackbot that creates a thread if it is mentioned in a channel and can subsequently interact with the user who mentioned it in the thread without being mentioned again. To achieve this I needed to subscribe to app_mentions and messages.channel in the events api. However, this caused a problem because when an app mention is sent to the channel the events api is hit twice, once for an app_mention and once for a message. To ensure the bot was responding appropriately I implemented code to find out if the bot was tagged in the message event. I did this by looking through the events object sent by slack to the bot. It seems the only way to find out if a user/bot has been tagged in the request sent through the message.channels event is by reviewing the actual text of the message. The text of an example message looks like this when I review the requests object: {"text": "<@WMBCCUPEE> hello there"}.

Knowing that my Bot Username on the backend is <@WMBCCUPEE> makes it easy to discern if the bot is being called in the message. The problem I am facing is that I haven't found any other way to determine this bot username outside of printing the request sent by the events api. I will be sending this application to other users who won't be able to view the bot username in the logs so I'm hoping someone is aware of another location that I can view the backend username for this bot? For more context, the actual bot is not named WMBCCUPPEE, when I mention it on the front end, I mention amlabot, its display name.

If you don't have an answer for that question, I'm also wondering if there is another way to tell if the message sent through the message.channel events api includes a mention. I've reviewed the requests sent by slack for both app_mention and message.channel and it appears they are pretty much the same except for the "type" key which will say app_mention or message depending on the event.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to ensure the bot is responding appropriately is to examine the event payload that is posted to your app. It is in JSON format and looks something like this:

```
{
        "token": "XXYYZZ",
        "team_id": "TXXXXXXXX",
        "api_app_id": "AXXXXXXXXX",
        "event": {
                "type": "name_of_event",
                "event_ts": "1234567890.123456",
                "user": "UXXXXXXX1",
                ...
        },
        "type": "event_callback",
        "authed_users": [
                "UXXXXXXX1",
                "UXXXXXXX2"
        ],
        "authorizations": {
            "enterprise_id": "E12345",
            "team_id": "T12345",
            "user_id": "U12345",
            "is_bot": false
        },
        "event_context": "EC12345",
        "event_id": "Ev08MFMKH6",
        "event_time": 1234567890
}
```

The best way around the problem you're having is to search the JSON for event.type which will give you the exact event type that is being posted. In order to respond only to the user that mentioned the app, you can use a simple if statement that posts a message to event.user only if event.type == "app_mention".